# A new tag, what is right name?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I am considering to add a tag, inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730206/how-do-i-use-multiple-data-locations-with-priam), referring to [this](https://github.com/Netflix/Priam). And for your convenience, here's [a search for the word](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=priam).

- First, does the tag seem reasonable? Alternatives seem to be tagging [netflix](/questions/tagged/netflix) + [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra).
- Then, which tag to choose? [priam](/questions/tagged/priam), [netflix-priam](/questions/tagged/netflix-priam), [cassandra-priam](/questions/tagged/cassandra-priam) or even something else?
- If I do create the tag, should I proceed to tag the old questions with it?

I'm also asking this to get better feel on what tag names are good, and what should be tagged, so linking to posts which give clear up-to-date guideline is welcome, if such posts exists.

Comment: Just `priam`...  Make sure you write a tag wiki for it, so users know what it means.

Comment: Done (wiki waiting for review). And yeah, just creating tag without wiki, for a question where people in comments ask what is it, would be kind of pointless :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *First, does the tag seem reasonable? Alternatives seem to be tagging [netflix](/questions/tagged/netflix) + [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra).*

Looks fine to me. A technology deserves its own tag.

> *Then, which tag to choose? [priam](/questions/tagged/priam), [netflix-priam](/questions/tagged/netflix-priam), [cassandra-priam](/questions/tagged/cassandra-priam) or even something else?*

I would name it [priam](/questions/tagged/priam), as I suspect that is unlikely to be ambiguous any time in the near future. We can always create synonyms if people insist on tagging with something different.

As Robert suggests in the comment, please take the time to write a tag wiki for it (or at least the excerpt) to help people know to select it.

> *If I do create the tag, should I proceed to tag the old questions with it?*

That would be great!